# Drop down box and search box to query Xml XSL

Tags: php, xml, xslt, jscript

I got a page spitting out my .xml feed/file content nicely using the easy to use ( i mean, easy to search for answers)  xsl stlyesheets and a bit of xpath logic to get the 'child' photo i want and select the elements in price order ascending etc..

Now I want to link the search bar and drop down menus to dynamically query the document...

I have tried about 4000 searches on stack etc., but it seems that nobody uses XML on webpages; they just use it for fun, parse it and then never use XML dynamically.

I still don't know if I should be storing the XML in a MySQL DB (which would be a nightmare with many tables) and querying that data: I have limped here from countless searches...

I can use PHP , JQuery etc., but don't know which way to aim as there is no black and white direction to follow on forums etc.

This is my XSLT so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>   
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
    <body>
a    
    <div>
    <select>
      <option value="a">Price To</option>
      <option value="b">£100,000</option>
      <option value="c">£200,000</option>
      <option value="d">£300,000</option>
      <option value="e">£400,000</option>
    </select>
    <select>
      <option value="a">Price From</option>
      <option value="b">£100,000</option>
      <option value="c">£200,000</option>
      <option value="d">£300,000</option>
      <option value="e">£400,000</option>
    </select>
         <div id="xsltsearch">
    <div class="xsltsearch_form">
    <form method="post" action="properties2_1.xml">
      <input name="search" type="text" class="input" value="" /> 
       <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
      <h2>Property Available </h2>
      <table >
        <tr bgcolor="#DCDCDC">
          <th>Address</th>
          <th>Bedrooms</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th>Picture</th>
        </tr>        
        <xsl:for-each select="agency/branches/branch/properties/property">
          <xsl:sort order="ascending" select="numeric_price" data-type="number"/>  
            <tr>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="advert_heading"/></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="bedrooms"/></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="numeric_price"/></td>
              <td><img src="{pictures/picture[1]/filename}" width="99px"></img></td>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>        
  </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```